Kendo Field with 4 decimal places No decimal rounding
The problem occurs when the value is entered and it is automatically converted to decimals Rond!
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                pageable: true,
                height: 700,
                toolbar: ["save"],
                columns: [                    
                    { field: "MonthName", title: "ماه", width: "120px" },
                    {
                        field: "Value", title: "مقدار", width: "120px", decimals: 4, format: "{0:n3}"},
                     
                ],
                editable: "incell"
            });

For Example Value : 0.0009  Converted To 0.0010
